# Can we use multiple symbols or color in MARKERATTRS option of SAS SGPLOT?

Tags: marker, sgplot

I want to combine Scatter and Series Graph using PROC SGPLOT. At some point I need to use different different symbols for my group data. I used Styleattrs option for this purpose. But when I try to add legend, I can not merge the symbols using keylegend. Since Markerattrs option automatically merges the symbols in the legend, I tried to use it. But I can not add multiple symbols with Markerattrs. So I want to know if there is any way to do this or I need to use Styleattrs?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. All I need to do is add the option "Markers" after my series plot.

```
SERIES X=value1 Y=value2 / GROUP=tpatt MARKERS;
KEYLEGEND 'SERIES';
```